# Is it possible to send one satoshi to every bitcoin address?

Tags: satoshi

As a random whim, I want to see if it's possible to send one satoshi to every bitcoin address that's ever been used. How much would that be? I'm betting the transaction fee would be a lot more, though. Is this even possible? How would I do it?

Comment: Hm.. kind of multicast. I am not sure how useful this could be, but it is not possible now. You need to create as many transactions required.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. There are currently about 10 million unique addresses in the block chain, so 0.1 BTC would be enough to send a satoshi to each address. The transaction data would be about 340 MB. The network's anti-spam protections would make this project either very expensive (due to transaction fees) or very time-consuming.

Comment: Thanks! So it's infeasible. =( As an estimate, how much do you think the transaction fee would be?

Comment: @lurfjurv It's not infeasible. The fee might be about 170 BTC, though this depends on many factors.

Comment: How do you know there are 10 million unique addresses?

Comment: @Shamoon I gathered that data from the block chain.

Comment: @theymos Is it up on blockchain.info anywhere?

Comment: @Shamoon I don't know. I didn't get the info from a website.

Comment: It's weird. I got a 1 satoshi transaction from 1Enjoy1C4bYBr3tN4sMKxvvJDqG8NkdR4Z. You don't need to provide a transaction fee, but it might be quite a while before a miner decides to process it.